# Writing a program in Tree data Structure, I have to write class name and user defined datatype Name is same why?

Tags: java, class, data-structures, binary-tree, user-defined-data-types

why we write like this,
Probably I  write like this  because here we have to need  to write user-defined datatype;
but it is mandatory to write the class name and user-defined datatype name is same, when I write the structure of Node class then I write like this

```
class tNode{ 
    tNode left;
    tNode right;
}
```

Why did we not write like this?

```
class tNode{
    Node left;
    Node right;
}
```

Comment: Java coding conventions have class names start with an upper case letter, so it would be "TNode". Variables and methods start with lower case letters.

Answer (score 0):

That's because a tree is made up of objects of the same type, pointing to other objects of the same type in one way or another. So `left` and `right` for a tree of `tNode` objects have to be the same type as `tNode`.

When you do recursive operations on a tree node, then each node would be assumed to be the starting point of a different tree (aka subtree). So `recursiveFunctione(node)` would lead to `recursiveFunctione(node.left)` and `recursiveFunctione(node.right)` Since java is strongly typed, if the nodes are of different types, then the recursive function would not work.

I suppose some kind of inheritance structure would open up different possibilities, but I'm not sure what that would be.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a situation where you try establishing a family relationship, you always relate one human -> another human and not any other living being.

Now this family relation can be expressed via a Tree, so it must use its own Class.

//Jus a light note..